# How to color highlight .htaccess files in Netbeans

Tags: .htaccess, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to get Netbeans to color the syntax of .htaccess files?

Even differentiating comments from code would be helpful

Comment: I think it is impossible at the moment, you can try assigning some filetype to `htaccess` but it won't work unless you put some valid character before coma in filename, so you will have to work on `_.htaccess` for example

Comment: Vote for this issue to get it added to a future version of Netbeans: [link](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166364)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [forum post](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/improvements_in_coloring), the feature is ready and scheduled for **NetBeans 7.2**

**Update:** Netbeans 7.2 is out and the feature is finally here. It works with both `.htaccess` and `*.conf` files and looks pretty complete:

[image]

In any case, syntax highlighting seems to be the only feature so far. There's nothing similar to code intelligence: no navigation, no *Show Documentation*, no container matching... not even auto-indent!

Comment: "Toggle Comment" is still missing, but all in all a great feature!